# RangeError when querying for big number using #where in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've just upgraded an old app from Rails 3.0 to 4.2 and now it is impossible to query the database for very long IDs.

## Rails 3

```
Product.where(associated_id: 1311344470881970878875083923).first
=> nil
```

## Rails 4.2.3

```
Product.where(associated_id: 1311344470881970878875083923).first
RangeError: 1311344470881970878875083923 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 8
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/type/integer.rb:45:in `ensure_in_range'
```

I'd expect that the finder returns nothing in Rails 4.2.3 as well in such a case. It's just searching for results, we don't need to call `ensure_in_range`.

UPDATE: however, the following works fine (it may serve as a workaround):

```
Product.find_by(associated_id: 1311344470881970878875083923)
```

It works because `find_by` is implemented as below:

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
rescue RangeError
  nil
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Unfortunately a similar method for returning all results is missing in ActiveRecord 4.2.3

```
def find_all_by(*args)
  where(*args).load
rescue RangeError
  none
end
```

Comment: thats a pretty big number for an integer!

Answer (score -1):

`1311344470881970878875083923` ist way out of the INT Range in postgres.
Every Datatype has its own range. a Integer normally presenting 4 bytes, which means there are 4294967294 different values. (-2147483647 till +2147483647 and a 0).

if you need those big numbers as the object_id, make sure to use a `bigint`. he can handle those.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html

**edit**

as on your edit, you can extend your ActiveRecord with ease

```
# config/initializer/active_record.rb

class ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.find_all_by(*args)
      where(*args).load
    rescue RangeError
      nil
  end
end
```

Comment: This really doesn't bring anything to this discussion. See the "UPDATE" section in my first post. What we're really missing is something like find_all_by . It doesn't matter what kind of number I'm sending to this query, it should not fail with such an error when I just want to find something in the database.

Comment: so why dont you implement your own "find_all" method?

Comment: Of course I can extend AR with my method. I was looking for some hints about implementing it using unmodified AR.